# docker nodejs nginx socket.io how to get actual ip of client not natted ip

Tags: node.js, sockets, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a project at http://github.com/KPB-US/dispatch-display and in it I determine what [fire] station a display [client] belongs to based on it's ip address when the socket connects.

I have a docker composition set up so it can be up and running easily using docker-compose build and docker-compose up.  This builds an nginx server that points to the upstream node application running on a node server.

Everything runs fine when I specify network_mode: "host" in both services in the docker-compose.yml.  I'd rather have it run more securely using dockers default network mode-- but when I do that, I get NATed [I guess, see example message below] ip addresses from the clients instead of their actual ip addresses, so I don't know which stations [clients] they are coming from.

> A connection attempt was made but that remote address is not
>   registered in the STATIONS list - 172.18.0.1

I am determining the incoming IP address based on the x-forwarded-for header and if missing, then the socket.conn.remoteAddress.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?  I'd like to keep the containers isolated from the network (as mentioned above) but yet still be able to know where the incoming connection is really coming from.

Comment: It looks like it is related to this issue : https://github.com/docker/for-azure/issues/7 which is related to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526  Trying to solve the same issue ...